Do citation and reference both convey these same two senses in the context of books?
When you read a book there often is a little number at the end of some sentences (that are usually quotes/or information from other sources).
Most of the time at the end of the book there will be a list that these numbers correspond to and next to them will be sources from which these corresponding quotes/or information were taken.
QUESTION:
Do the words citation and reference both describe these things: the text in a book with the numbers and the listing at the end of it showing the source? I'm asking because the definition for "reference" uses the word "citation" in its explanation (see below) which is circular and doesn't specify which sense of "citation" is meant in its explanation:
citation:
a quotation from or reference to a book, paper, or author, especially in a scholarly work.
"the majority of the citations are to work published during the past twenty years"
reference:
a mention or citation of a source of information in a book or article.
"each chapter should have references to books covering the subject in greater depth"
a source of information cited in a book or article."
(Both definition come from Oxford Languages Dictionary)

There are two or three different exact senses of the noun citation in your context (plus other irrelevant obsolete and/or legal senses). The three in full OED that should interest you (note when first recorded) are 2.a. 1538– The action or an act of quoting or referring to a passage, text, author, legal precedent, etc., esp. as an authority or in support of an argument; quotation.
2.b. 1548– A cited passage, a quotation.
2.c. 1721– A reference providing information about where a particular quotation, text, etc., is to be found; a bibliographical reference.

I sometimes use just cite for the 3rd sense above, so I just checked that. Full OED says that's a US usage. But I think OED say that about dialog in all contexts, whereas to me it's a dialog box in computing contexts, and a dialogue is something two people engage in (usually, but not always orally) to exchange information, agree compromises, etc. So I'm a part-US Brit!

They're very close in meaning and are nearly interchangeable. I'd say citation is more closely associated with the numbering in the text itself, as it connotes the particular passage that is being cited. Reference, on the other hand, just connotes that something was referred to, and might be more associated with the list of media you consulted at the end.
It would be possible to include references without citations if you just listed the books you consulted but didn't denote the specific passages where you used them. It probably would not be possible to include citations without references. In most cases you could probably refer to both citations and references as references, but I might not in all cases refer to a reference as a citation. That said, it would be quite persnickety to insist that a citation includes only the numbering in the text but not where it points to, and that the list defining the citation references is not actually part of the citation.

It's a great answer and I'm happy that I learned the word hoagie as well as persnickety today but I've got a question. You used the word "denote" in a way that I not full understand "if you just listed the books you consulted but didn't denote the specific passages where you used them". Can you tell me in what sense did you use this word here?

@StaticBounce "Denote" is to indicate something. The citation numbers denote which passages in the text correspond to which references.

I know this word in this sense e.g "This number denotes the amount of players that can enter the court" but you used it differently. You used denote as if it was an action that I performed "It would be possible to include references without citations if you just listed the books you consulted but didn't denote the specific passages where you used them. ". If I supplant denote for specify in this context it makes sense for me but I never heard "denote" used this way. Are you sure this is correct way to use it? Can you provide another example in which a person denotes something?

@StaticBounce You are better off using: number of players

@StaticBounce See the third definition here, "to make known". https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/denote. The number itself denotes which reference the passage corresponds to in the sense of "serving as a marker for", but by applying the number, you yourself are also denoting in the sense of "making it known" that this is, in fact, a citation. Both the mark itself and the author who put the mark there are making an indication.

Question:
Do the words citation and reference both describe these things: the text in a book with the numbers and the listing at the end of it showing the source?
Are those both citations and references?
Answer:
Those numbers refer to footnotes or endnotes. Footnotes can be placed at the bottom of a page OR at the end of the book, and then are called endnotes. The numbers appear first at the end of a sentence in superscript or in parentheses.
Those numbers are given for references or citations.
Footnotes and endnotes

Footnotes or endnotes are how you give credit to a source in the text itself. You use a superscript number in the text that corresponds
to a note with citation information at the end of the document
(endnotes) or at the bottom of the page (footnotes).
Footnotes/endnotes are formatted differently than bibliography
citations.

footnotes and the term citation
We say: to cite references. References are in a bibliography OR in a footnote. There are style rules for them from various sources like the Chicago Manual of Style.
In a formal paper, mentioning works by others or quoting them OR providing explanatory footnotes in a the paper is citation or reference.
The Rationale Behind Citations

The main reason for citing references properly is to avoid
intellectual dishonesty (Bast & Samuels, 2008). Presenting ideas of
other scholars without proper research paper citation goes against
scientific ethics (Gross, 2016). While this is not the highest of
ethical requirements, it is simply basic decency. This is because we
humans have a strong sense of ownership, not just of our physical
properties but also of our intellectual works and achievements. We
have a strong drive to know who or where exactly pieces of information
came from and how ideas develop. Thus it is important to know how to
give reference in a research paper.
How to cite a research paper

citations and references:

Scientific Style and Format Citation Quick Guide
Scientific Style and Format presents three systems for referring to references (also known as citations) within the text of a journal
article, book, or other scientific publication: 1) citation–sequence;
2) name–year; and 3) citation–name. These abbreviated references are
called in-text references. They refer to a list of references at the
end of the document.
The system of in-text references that you use will determine the order
of references at the end of your document. These end references have
essentially the same format in all three systems, except for the
placement of the date of publication in the name–year system.
Quick guide to citations aka references

The nouns citation and reference can be interchangeable but the verb cite is more commonly used like this: to cite a reference to an author or work in a paper or provide a reference (in a footnote or bibliography).
